# Trouble hovering over td with rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

I am having some issues when I am trying to hover over a td with rowspan. I couldn't find a solution. I saw on some forums that I might need JS/jQuery...Can someone give me a solution? I will show you my code.. I just need something to start and I can work it out after....

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Sunday</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>7:00</td>
      <td rowspan="8" style="background-color:rgb(0,187,109)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Cardiology</br> <span class="tt-table-r"> Room 16 </span> </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 07:00 - 11:00 </span></br> Dr. Max Turner</p>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color:rgb(242,243,248);"></td>
      <td rowspan="5" style="background-color:rgb(0,182,255)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Neurology</br> <span class="tt-table-r"> Room 11 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 07:00 - 9:00 </span></br> Dr. Jason Clark</p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="10" style="background-color:rgb(222,184,135)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Ophtalmology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 25 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 07:00 - 12:00 </span></br> Dr. Amy Adams</p>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color:rgb(242,243,248);"></td>
      <td rowspan="7" style="background-color:rgb(199,115,191)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Traumatology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 32 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 07:00 - 10:30 </span></br> Dr. Peter Wilson</p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="7" style="background-color:rgb(0,187,109)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Cardiology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 16 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 07:00 - 10:30 </span></br> Dr. Max Turner</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan="3" style="background-color:rgb(0,182,255)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Neurology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 11 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 07:30 - 9:00 </span></br> Dr. Jason Clark</p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(0,182,255)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Dentistry</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 11 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 07:00 - 9:00 </span></br> Dr. Jason Clark</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>8:00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>9:00</td>
      <td rowspan="3" style="background-color:rgb(0,187,109)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Cardiology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 16 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 09:00 - 10:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr"> Dr. Max Turner</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan="7" style="background-color:rgb(255,104,90)">
          <p class="tt-table-p">Pediatrics</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 15 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 09:30 - 13:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Julia Jameson</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>10:00</td>
      <td rowspan="5" style="background-color:rgb(199,115,191)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Traumatology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 32 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 10:00 - 12:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Peter Wilson</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan="3" style="background-color:rgb(255,104,90)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Pediatrics</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 15 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 10:30 - 12:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Julia Jameson</p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="6" style="background-color:rgb(76,76,191)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Diagnostics</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 15 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 10:30 - 13:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Helen Wilson</p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(199,115,191)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Traumatology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 32 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 10:30 - 12:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Peter Wilson</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>11:00</td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(0,182,255)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Dentistry</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 11 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 11:00 - 13:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Jason Clark</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>12:00</td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(0,106,121)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Pulmonary</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 113 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 12:00 - 14:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Rodney Stratton </span></p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(0,106,121)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Pulmonary</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 113 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 12:00 - 14:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Rodney Stratton </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan="5" style="background-color:rgb(255,104,90)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Pediatrics</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 15 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 12:30 - 15:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Julia Jameson </span></p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="5" style="background-color:rgb(222,184,135)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Ophtalmology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 25 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 12:30 - 15:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Amy Adams </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>13:00</td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(222,184,135)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Ophtalmology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 25 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 13:00 - 15:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Amy Adams </span></p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="5" style="background-color:rgb(199,115,191)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Traumatology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 32 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 13:00 - 15:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Peter Wilson </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan="5" style="background-color:rgb(0,187,109)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Cardiology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 16 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 13:30 - 16:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Max Turner </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>14:00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan="6" style="background-color:rgb(199,115,191)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Traumatology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 32 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 14:30 - 17:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Peter Wilson </span></p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="5" style="background-color:rgb(0,187,109)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Cardiology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 16 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 14:30 - 17:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Max Turner </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td rowspan="5" style="background-color:rgb(0,187,109)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Cardiology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 16 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 15:00 - 17:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Max Turner </span></p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="5" style="background-color:rgb(0,106,121)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Pulmonary</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 113 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 15:00 - 17:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Rodney Stratton </span></p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(0,106,121)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Pulmonary</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 113 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 15:00 - 17:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Rodney Stratton </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(255,104,90)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Pediatrics</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 15 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 15:30 - 17:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Julia Jameson </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>16:00</td>
      <td rowspan="7" style="background-color:rgb(255,104,90)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Pediatrics</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 15 </span>  </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 16:30 - 19:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Julia Jameson </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>17:00</td>
      <td rowspan="5" style="background-color:rgb(76,76,191)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Diagnostics</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 15 </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 17:00 - 19:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Helen Wilson </span></p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="5" style="background-color:rgb(76,76,191)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Diagnostics</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 15 </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 10:30 - 13:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Helen Wilson </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(255,104,90)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Pediatrics</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 15 </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 17:30 - 19:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Julia Jameson </span></p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(0,106,121)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Pulmonary</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 113 </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 17:30 - 19:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Rodney Stratton </span></p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(222,184,135)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Ophtalmology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 25 </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 12:30 - 15:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Amy Adams </span></p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(222,184,135)">
        <p class="tt-table-p">Ophtalmology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 25 </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 12:30 - 15:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Amy Adams </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>18:00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>19:00</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>



.tt-table-container table tr th {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:14px;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    text-align:center;
}

.tt-table-container table {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:30px;
}

.tt-table-container table tr td {
    height:60px;

}

.tt-table-container table tr td {
    width:12.5%;
        font-size:15.5px;

}

.tt-table-container table tr td[rowspan]{
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top:20px;
    font-size:13.5px;
}

.tt-table-container table tr:nth-child(2n) td:first-of-type {
    background-color:rgb(242,243,248);
    font-size:14px;
}

.tt-table-p {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.tt-table-r {
    font-size:14px;
}

.tt-table-hours {
    font-size:13.5px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.tt-table-dr {
    font-size:13.5px;
}

.tt-green:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

and I am trying to reproduce this table with the hover effect:

https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/69211.html  after opening the template go to "Deparments" from the menu.

Comment: Please don't paste code off-site, only to provide a link. Such resources can and do become unreliable, rendering the original question useless.

Comment: I see that you have .tt-green:hover {
    background-color:red;
} but I dont see any element with that class

Comment: That was something that I tried and I forgot to delete it from the css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the mouseover in javascript function to try and fix this problem. you change the color of the td (or do anything else you want) in the "onmouseover" and change it back in the "onmouseout".

see my code:

**HTML: **

```
<tr>
          <td></td>
          <td onmouseover="changeColorRed(this)" onmouseout="normalColor(this)" rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(255,104,90)">
            <p class="tt-table-p">Pediatrics</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 15 </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 17:30 - 19:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Julia Jameson </span></p>
          </td>
          <td onmouseover="changeColorRed(this)" onmouseout="normalColor(this)" rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(0,106,121)">
            <p class="tt-table-p">Pulmonary</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 113 </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 17:30 - 19:30 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Rodney Stratton </span></p>
          </td>
          <td onmouseover="changeColorRed(this)" onmouseout="normalColor(this)" rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(222,184,135)">
            <p class="tt-table-p">Ophtalmology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 25 </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 12:30 - 15:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Amy Adams </span></p>
          </td>
          <td onmouseover="changeColorRed(this)" onmouseout="normalColor(this)" rowspan="4" style="background-color:rgb(222,184,135)">
            <p class="tt-table-p">Ophtalmology</br> <span class="tt-table-r">  Room 25 </br></br> <span class="tt-table-hours"> 12:30 - 15:00 </span></br></br> <span class="tt-table-dr">  Dr. Amy Adams </span></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeColorRed(x) {
    var temp = x.style.backgroundColor;
    localStorage.setItem("color", temp); // store the last backgroundColor
    x.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function normalColor(x) {
    var lastColor = localStorage.getItem('color'); // find the last backgroundColor
    x.style.backgroundColor = lastColor;
}
```

Comment: This works great for one color. But if I want each td to change to a different colour how can I fix it ? tried something but I couldn't manage it.. thank you..the only solution that I found is creating a new script file for each color lol

Comment: Hi, You can add to the "changeColorRed" the color you want to change, and then it will change dynamically as you choose. like this: [link]https://jsfiddle.net/ate983Lg/3/  Note: I didn;t success to add the Javascript to the JS window so the JavaScript code embedded in the HTML code (before closing the body tag)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it was just what I needed

Comment: My pleasure :))